# How to deploy MEAN Stack to web host

Tags: angularjs, node.js, git, heroku, mean-stack

I have a node API and an angular front end project (via grunt, bower, yeoman flow structure) as two separate github repositories. I am trying to push them both to production through Heroku. Coming from a rails bg where everything in the app exists in the same project directory, and you only have to push one directory, how would you do this? Should I push both projects as separate heroku projects or is there a best practice out there? I'd appreciate any and all advice, thank you in advance.

Comment: added a few more details...

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I would review the [official Heroku doc on deploying nodejs apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs)

If you have two projects, you will probably want to deploy them as different heroku apps.

The key here is going to be making sure your package.json is set up correctly.  Make sure all your dependencies are correct and present, and your package.json points to your node server script.  Make sure you have your dev dependencies like grunt separate from your production dependencies also, as these don't need to be deployed to production.  If this is just a demo app, you can have heroku install all your scripts (like angular) simply by including them in your package.json.  When you push your app, it will run an `npm install` on your package.json and install it the dependencies.

There are a few ways you can deploy also - via the heroku cli, a github link, or a dropbox link.  I haven't personally used the cli much, but I have found the other two convenient to use, especially if you are already pushing to github.

One key thing too is that if you need to install dependencies with bower, you should know that heroku **DOES NOT** run `bower install` on it's own.  You can tell heroku to run it by adding the following to your package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "bower install"
}
```

This will cause it to run a `bower install` after `npm install` finishes.

Also, if you haven't done so already, you'll need to set up your database somewhere with a 3rd party provider (like [mongolab](https://mongolab.com/) or [modulus](https://modulus.io/)).